# Ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save on String ID

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Already read lots of questions about the same issue, but I still not be able to solve this problem.

I need to have a `String` primary key on my database.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    private String myId;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters..

}
```

The problem is that, if I use `String` type in a `@Id` annotated field, Hibernate throws an exception when I try to save the object.

```
ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling
```

And yes, I'm setting a value to the field.

Workarounds I found:

1. Add `@GeneratedValue` annotation to the field - not worked
2. Change the field type to `Integer` - it's not feasible for me
3. Add a constructor that receives `myId` as parameter `public MyClass(String myId){ ... }` - not worked
4. Use UUID - i can't, cause this id is set by a field that comes in with a POST request.

None of these workarounds worked for me.

**UPDATE**

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA.

How do I insert:

I have an `@PostMapping` annotated method which handles POST request and call a service that do some business logic and call my repository for persisting.

The request I post:

```
{
    "myId": "myId",
    "name": "myName"
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public MyClass save(MyClass myClass) {
        return myRepository.save(myClass); // save() should persist my object into the database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this approach

```
@Entity
public class MyClass{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = “UUID”)
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = “UUID”,
        strategy = “org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator”,
    )
    @Column(name = “id”, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    …
}
```

======================================

I invoke like this and in my envirenment all work fine:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PostMapping("")
@Transactional
public void add(@RequestBody MyClass myClass){
        entityManager.persist(myClass);
}
```

and requst send by post with body:

```
{
    "myId" : "213b2bbb1"
}
```

Comment: I cannot use UUID. This primary key is set by a field which comes in a POST request.

Comment: @MatheusCirillo ok, try only add @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) for private String myId;

Comment: Unfortunately, other errors raises.
`"Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String"`

Comment: @MatheusCirillo my question, how do you insert record ? do you use `entityManager.persist` ?

Comment: Make sure you send `myId` as not null

Comment: I'm using Spring Data JPA. Question updated describing how I persist data.

Comment: change to `entityManager.persist(myClass)` and make sure `myId` is not null, it should works

Answer (score 2):

Based on the helpful answer by @PiotrRogowski, for numeric primary keys, for example those mapped to `java.lang.Long`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myclass")
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Incremental")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "Incremental",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator",
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
        
    …
}
```

---

You can invoke it this way:

```java
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
    
@PostMapping("")
@Transactional
public void add(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
    entityManager.persist(myClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem, turns out I was missing the setter for the id field. Make sure the setter method for the ID is defined in the entity class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).