# How to manually set a value for @GeneratedValue

Tags: jpa, id-generation

Have a Spring boot with Spring Data JPA. Postgres DB.

General entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
class Entity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

}
```

when I try to make an entry with a specified `id` value, as a result I see that it is ignored and generated by `@GeneratedValue`.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Are you using a jpa repository or crud ?

Comment: Going by the flow of CRUD repo

Comment: try to make your repository inherit from JpaRepository<Entity,int>

Comment: Check this it might help..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89439/bypass-generatedvalue-in-hibernate

Comment: @Yosra, tried. Same

Comment: @ReetaWani, running a fresh db with all possible sequences cleaned up and etc + trying different generation strategies. No luck.

Comment: Try doing this `@GeneratedValue(generator = "org.hibernate.id.Assigned")`

Comment: Assigned is the default generator strategy if there is no <generator> element . In this case, application assigns the id. AppleBuckler if you remove "@GeneratedValue" then it will work and assign user given ID. But i don't think you need that..

Comment: "org.hibernate.id.Assigned" on this I get a `Could not instantiate id generator`.

Comment: @ReetaWani, yes, that's the thing I'm trying to handle - have a GeneratedValue when the ID is null/0, and use the provided when there is one.

Comment: try to inspire from this answer by personalizing its add function by generating random id if it's not provided. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52010963/13101111

Comment: well, the ID is used not only for row identification, so making it as UUID isn't a possibility

Comment: Thanks all for the input. After doing some good old debug the whole thing investigation, I've struck on many interesting things like "it's merged by default", "no persistantId at all" and "SequenceGenerator ignores the provided entity to persist" I went the road of GenericGenerator and it works quite well.

Comment: Could you make the final comment a proper answer, so others see this is answered?

Comment: Sure. Not sure though if the solution is the one, which is intended to be...

Answer (score 2):

Posting the solution, to which I came after doing a debug of the whole persist process (not stating that this is the right way, but I literally didn't find any spot of "maybe I configured something wrong"):

```
public class MyGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return Optional.of(object)
                .filter(Entity.class::isInstance)
                .map(Entity.class::cast)
                .map(Entity::getId)
                .filter(i -> i > 0)
                .map(Serializable.class::cast)
                .orElseGet(() -> super.generate(session, object));
    }
)
```

and the entity:

```
@Entity
class Entity implements Serializable {

@GenericGenerator(name = "myGenerator", strategy = "org.a.b.c.generators.MyGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "myGenerator")
    private Integer id;

}
```