# Spring data. How can I update an entity, having the id modified?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

Spring data jpa + postgres.

Have an entity

```
class Entity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue// generator from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989691/how-to-manually-set-a-value-for-generatedvalue/61007375#61007375
private int id;

private String value;

}
```

And what I wish to do is to UPDATE an existing entity, setting a different id (be it a bad practice or not) value.

By default it of course is treated as a new entity and is attempted to be INSERTed.

Going by the flow of `@Modifying` seems to do the job right, but currently struggling to find if I can pass the whole entity instead of pinpointing every field:

`update Entity e set e.id=?1, e.value=?2 where...`
to
`update Entity e set e=?1`

So the questions here would be:
1. Is there a way to gracefully do an "UPDATE" with modified id in terms or regular spring-data-jpa flow?
2. If not, is there a way to provide the full entity to be consumed by the `@Query`?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a way to gracefully do an "UPDATE" with modified id in terms or regular spring-data-jpa flow?

If you are using [`GenerationType.AUTO` strategy for `@GeneratedValue`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO) (`AUTO` is the default strategy), then you can set `id` of `Entity` to `null` before calling `save`. It will insert a new record with rest of the fields being the same as original. `id` of new record will be generated automatically by database engine.

If you are using `GenerationType.AUTO` strategy for `@GeneratedValue`

> 2. If not, is there a way to provide the full entity to be consumed by the `@Query`?

You can chose not use `@Query`. A far simpler approach can be using default [`save` method provided by JPA repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-) to directly pass an `Entity` object.

Comment: My answer assumes that you are using `AUTO` strategy (which is default if none is provided). But, the same approach can be used for other id generation strategies as well.

Comment: Sorry, but my case is "I want to manually define the ID"(and no, `@GeneratedValue` should remain) and have query be resolved to UPDATE.